# Word for evil in the name of good

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call when someone is doing something bad in the name of something he believes to be truly good and even greater than his individual actions?

- war in the name of freedom
- murder in the name of god
- lie to congress to fulfil the destiny of your country

etc.

Comment: That would be [*the road to hell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_road_to_hell_is_paved_with_good_intentions), but of course that's not a single word.

Comment: "Evil".  Because, well, sometimes, terrible things done in the name of good are not good at all, but merely terrible things - and evil things done in the name of good, are still just evil.

Comment: Another phrase, "the greater good".

Comment: @fixer1234 [the greater good](http://i.imgur.com/U57Tg8O.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Not a single word, but "The end justifies the means."
The end (result) justifies the means (of getting there).

Comment: Also consider: *consequentialism*.

Answer (score 1):

He might be doing it - [***for the greater good***](http://www.yourdictionary.com/greater-good). That is, he considers it to be a small price to pay for achieving something he believes will be beneficial in a larger scale to a greater amount of people.

> - The benefit of the public, of more people than oneself; that which is better and more correct.

The *price to be payed* and the *outcome* to be achieved are subjective and depends how *he* (the actor) perceives them to be.

Answer (score 0):

***[misguided](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misguided)***

> Adj.
>
> 1. misguided - poorly conceived or thought out; "an ill-conceived plan to take over the company"
>
>    ill-conceived
>
>    foolish - devoid of good sense or judgment; "foolish remarks"; "a foolish decision"
> 2. misguided - wrong in e.g. opinion or judgment; "well-meaning but misguided teachers"; "a mistaken belief"; "mistaken identity"
>
>    mistaken
>
>    wrong - contrary to conscience or morality or law; "it is wrong for the rich to take advantage of the poor"; "cheating is wrong"; "it is wrong to lie"

(Wordnet)